# How to align text and a table next to each other

Tags: tables, minipage

I want to produce a table-like structure but preceeded by a single word on the left, like so:

[image: variable descriptions]

Here is what I tried:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
Here \\
\begin{tabular}{ccl}
$n$    & --- & the number of the term in the sequence---positive integer or zero;\\
$N$    & --- & value of the $n$-th term of the sequence $\left\{ F_n \right\}$; \\
$F(n)$ & --- & value of the $n$-th term of sequence $\left\{ F_n \right\}$ as a function of its number---lower index $n$.
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
```

and the result (of course my lines don't even wrap around - I was going to tackle that next):

[image: my attempt]

What am I doing wrong here (for minipage positioning at least)?

Comment: Why don't you include the word (in this case, "Here") as the upper-left most table entry, and have blank entries below it?

Comment: That just feels "dirty"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Here` could be put into a first column. The text can be wrapped by using `p` columns. However `p` columns require a width. Package `tabularx` provides `X` columns that are `p` columns that automatically use the available space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{@{}lccX@{}}
Here
& $n$    & --- & the number of the term in the sequence---positive integer or zero;\\
& $N$    & --- & value of the $n$-th term of the sequence $\left\{ F_n \right\}$; \\
& $F(n)$ & --- & value of the $n$-th term of sequence $\left\{ F_n \right\}$ as a function of its number---lower index $n$.
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The `minipage` is no longer necessary.
- `@{}` removes the space `\tabcolsep` at the left and right hand sides of the table.

### Variant with nested tables

If you do not want to clobber the original table with surrounding text, `tabularx` can also be nested:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{@{}lX@{}}
Here &
  {%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]%
      {@{}>{$}c<{$} >{\hangindent=1em \hangafter=1 is the }X@{}}
    n    & number of the term in the sequence---positive integer or zero;\\
    N    & value of the $n$-th term of the sequence $\left\{ F_n \right\}$; \\
    F(n) & value of the $n$-th term of sequence $\left\{ F_n \right\}$ as a function of its number---lower index $n$.
    \end{tabularx}%
  }
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The inner `tabularx` needs to be enclosed in curly braces.
- The word `here` is aligned with the first row of the inner table, if `[t]` is given for the inner `tabularx`. If lines are used, then check out `\firsthline` of package `array`. Otherwise the baseline of `Here` would be aligned with the top `\hline`.
- `X` column provide `\linewidth` with the width of the column.
- The example shows, how package `array` can help for automatic insertions in table cells. Math mode is set for the first column and the words `is the` are added to the second column.
- For better visibility for this version without dash I have indented the followup lines of a table row by `1em` (`\hangindent=1em \hangafter=1`).

Comment: When you say "text is wrapped in p columns" - where is the `p` in your code? Sorry, but I don't see it.

Comment: @drozzy: `p` columns require the specification of a width. `tabularx` provides a `X` column specifier; `X` columns are `p` columns with a width that fills the available space.

Comment: Oh I see! I am curious, why does minipage not work? Why can't i have the word "Here" in the left minipage and the table in the righ?

Comment: @drozzy: Of course, also wrapping the whole thing in a `minipage` would work, but for what purpose? Also you can put all in one text line `Here~\begin{tabular}[t]...`, but then you do not know the available space for the `p` column or the available space for `tabularx`.

Answer (score 3):

If page-breaking is not a concern, then [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) can help here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\begin{document}
Here is some text before.

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}ll@{ --- }X@{}}
  Here
  & $n$ & the number of the term in the sequence---positive integer or zero; \\
  & $N$ & value of the $n$-th term of the sequence $\{ F_n \}$; \\
  & $F(n)$ & value of the $n$-th term of sequence $\{ F_n \}$ as a function of its number---lower index~$n$.
\end{tabularx}

Here is some text after.
\end{document}
```

I've added the text boundary border (using [`showframe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe), even though it's not included in the code above). Note the difference in using `\noindent`. This may not be applicable.

Comment: Thanks. Does it do text-wrapping?

Comment: @drozzy: Yes - the `X`-column is a variable-width column that wraps its contents. It expands until `\linewidth` (the first argument to `tabularx`) is reached. The use of `@{}` removes the column padding on either side so that the table is flush left/right. Also `@{ --- }` automatically inserts the `---` between columns two and three.

Comment: @drozzy: You can still use `tabular`. `tabularx` is only helpful if you have a variable-width column. If not, then you can use `p{<len>}` and you don't need to supply the table width.